# Math font in beamer class in LyX

Tags: beamer, math-mode, lyx

How do I get LMR or CMR math font in beamer class in LyX? In the document settings when I change the font only the text is affected and not the equations.

Comment: `bemear` uses CM by default: you must be making some font changes to get a different font in the first place.

Comment: @JosephWright I already tried the default settings. I still don't get CMR

Comment: Ah, you want the `serif` option. I'll post an answer, but as it's for 'standard' LaTeX there may be more to say for Lyx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

into the "Document->Setting->LaTeX preamble", then `beamer` didn't change anything in the math fonts

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly. Thanks @Herbert.